# Create JSON Object with Dynamic Array Name

Tags: java, json

I am trying to create a JSON Object from a database but I am struggling with the array name. 
The created JSON Object should look like this:

```
{
 "Table_name":{ "table_column_name":Value}
}
```

For instance if we have a table called Test and a column ID with value 123:

```
{ "Test" : { "ID":123}}
```

My code is:

```
public static JSONArray extractToJson(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    JSONArray json = new JSONArray();

    resultmetadata = rs.getMetaData();
    while (rs.next()) {

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject();

        for (int i = 1; i <= resultmetadata.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            String column_name_title = resultmetadata.getColumnName(i);
            String column_name = resultmetadata.getColumnName(i);

            if (resultmetadata.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.ARRAY) {
                obj.put(column_name_title, rs.getArray(column_name));
            } else if (resultmetadata.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.BIGINT) {
                obj.put(column_name_title, rs.getInt(column_name));
            } else if (resultmetadata.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.BOOLEAN) {
                obj.put(column_name_title, rs.getBoolean(column_name));
            } else if (resultmetadata.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.BLOB) {
                obj.put(column_name_title, rs.getBlob(column_name));
            } else if (resultmetadata.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.DOUBLE) {
                obj.put(column_name_title, rs.getDouble(column_name));
            } else if (resultmetadata.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.FLOAT) {
                obj.put(column_name_title, rs.getFloat(column_name));
            } else if (resultmetadata.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.INTEGER) {
                obj.put(column_name_title, rs.getInt(column_name));
            } else if (resultmetadata.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.NVARCHAR) {
                obj.put(column_name_title, rs.getNString(column_name));
            } else if (resultmetadata.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.VARCHAR) {
                obj.put(column_name_title, rs.getString(column_name));
            } else if (resultmetadata.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.TINYINT) {
                obj.put(column_name_title, rs.getInt(column_name));
            } else if (resultmetadata.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.SMALLINT) {
                obj.put(column_name_title, rs.getInt(column_name));
            } else if (resultmetadata.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.DATE) {
                obj.put(column_name_title, rs.getDate(column_name));
            } else if (resultmetadata.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP) {
                obj.put(column_name_title, rs.getTimestamp(column_name));
            } else {
                obj.put(column_name_title, rs.getObject(column_name));
            }

        }
        json.put(obj);

    }
    return json;
}
```

Where it produces a JSON like:

```
 {
  "ID": 123,
 }
```

This JSON File does not create any table name and it is something that we must have.

Comment: If you want to clean up your code a bit, look into the use of a switch case: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to use another object like obj2. And do something like :

```
obj2.put("Test",obj);
```

Comment: test it , you will be surprised ,  you have to put `obj2` into `json`

Comment: I've tried this but the problem is that the Name should be dynamic.For instance I did something like : obj2.put(resultmetadata.getTableName(i),json) but it produced nothing.

Comment: @MikeM.Kaspin use `json.put(obj2);` instead of `json.put(obj);`

Comment: Or `json.put(resultmetadata.getTableName(i),obj)`, if he does not want to use the intermediate obj2 object.

Comment: Ok I think I am almost there. Should I add obj2.put(resultmetadata.getTableName(i),obj); to each if statement and then add a json.put(obj2) after the if? I've tested but it produces a big {table_name: { all the table columns}} object